# Why does a simple array cause gcc to fail without a error message?

Tags: arrays, c

following code when included in kernel.h

```
#define MEMORY_GB 1
#define MEMORY_SIZE 100000*1024*MEMORY_GB

char memory[MEMORY_SIZE];
```

causes gcc to stop working

```
make: *** [kernel.x86_64.elf] Error 1
In file included from kernel.c:111:
libs/graphics.h: At top level:
libs/graphics.h:12:6: warning: conflicting types for 'cleardevice'
   12 | void cleardevice(){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
kernel.c:90:9: note: previous implicit declaration of 'cleardevice' was here
   90 |         cleardevice();
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from kernel.c:111:
libs/graphics.h:28:6: warning: conflicting types for 'setbkcolor'
   28 | void setbkcolor(uint32_t color){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~
kernel.c:89:9: note: previous implicit declaration of 'setbkcolor' was here
   89 |         setbkcolor(YELLOW);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from kernel.c:114:
idt.h:25:6: warning: conflicting types for 'InitializeIDT'
   25 | void InitializeIDT(){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
kernel.c:69:5: note: previous implicit declaration of 'InitializeIDT' was here
   69 |     InitializeIDT();
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from kernel.c:114:
idt.h: In function 'InitializeIDT':
idt.h:38:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'RemapPic' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   38 |  RemapPic();
      |  ^~~~~~~~
idt.h: At top level:
idt.h:46:6: warning: conflicting types for 'RemapPic'
   46 | void RemapPic(){
      |      ^~~~~~~~
idt.h:38:2: note: previous implicit declaration of 'RemapPic' was here
   38 |  RemapPic();
      |  ^~~~~~~~
In file included from kernel.c:113:
core/memory.h: In function 'malloc':
core/memory.h:27:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   27 | }
      | ^
In file included from kernel.c:115:
drivers/ps2/keyboard.h: In function 'scanCodeToKey':
drivers/ps2/keyboard.h:9:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    9 | }
```

on terminal there is no errors outputted by gcc in first place which is odd it returns with 1 as exit code which make complains about that, but when array size changed to 1 it magically works aren't there is no limit for array size in C? Another odd thing is even though this fail happens in build time and there shouldn't be a issue with the kernel itself

Another odd finding when i remove the macros and directly write with a random length like 400

```
char memory[400];
```

again same issue huh but

```
char memory[1];
```

works perfectly fine

Despite my attempts at googling why something like happens there was no results.

Here is some information about my system:
Build Env: Linux Lubuntu
Compiler: Gnu Gcc cross compiler x86_64-elf-gcc (GCC) 10.2.0

Sidenote: Kernel was working perfectly just the issue is that weird array problem on the memory manager

Comment: Unrelated: maybe `unsigned char memory[whatever];` is better?

Comment: Where is the variable declared? Locally or at file scope? Also those compiler warnings are all about library naming/installation hiccups so I don't see how they are related.

Comment: It is declared globally on the memory.h which contains my own (awful) implemention of calloc and malloc with a huge array used as a memory block to insert data on runtime, memory.h is being #include d on kernel.h

Comment: Why have you put a function implementation in a header file? And why is `char memory[MEMORY_SIZE];` in a header file?

Comment: Is there a limit for array size? In MSVC, yes.

Comment: All these warnings are not related to any array. But after touching a header that is used again and again, multiple files are re-compiled with all the ugly details showing up again

Comment: With that array in the header, every C file including that header will get an own copy of that array. Same for all functions you define there. That's a no-no.

Comment: Do not put function and data definitions into header hiles